# Using floodfill to count adjecent zeros in matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, flood-fill

I'm trying to count the number of adjecent zeros per group of zeros. I used a modified version of floodfill which returns the number of elements it filled. I then put the call to floodfill inside a loop. I don't understand whats wrong with it.

Correct output:
2 4

Current output:
2 2 2

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] in = getInput();
        char[][] map = getMap(Arrays.copyOfRange(in, 0, in.length));
        House h = new House(map);
        System.out.println(h);

    }

    private static String[] getInput() {
        String[] ret = {
                "11111",
                "10011",
                "11101",
                "10001",
                "11111"
            };
        return  ret;
    }

    private static char[][] getMap(String[] copyOfRange) {
        List<char[]> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String x : copyOfRange) 
            ret.add(x.toCharArray());
        return  ret.toArray(new char[ret.size()][]);
    }

}

class House {
    private char[][] map;
    List<Integer> listOfAreas;
    House(char[][] map) {
        this.map = map;
        listOfAreas = getAreas();
    }


    private List<Integer> getAreas() {
        List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        char[][] cMap = map.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < cMap.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cMap[i].length; j++) {
                if (cMap[i][j] == '0')
                    ret.add(countFlood(new Point(i,j),cMap));
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private int countFlood(Point start, char[][] cMap) {
        int count = 0;
        Stack<Point> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(start);
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            Point p = stack.pop();
            if (cMap[p.getX()][p.getY()] == '0') {
                ++count;
                cMap[p.getX()][p.getY()] = '1';
                for (Point x : getAdj(p,cMap))
                    stack.push(x);

            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    private Point[] getAdj(Point p, char[][] cMap) {
        List<Point> ret = new ArrayList<Point>();
        if (p.getX() == 0)
            ret.add(new Point(p.getX() - 1, p.getY()));
        if (p.getX() != cMap.length - 1)
            ret.add(new Point(p.getX() + 1, p.getY()));
        if (p.getY() == 0)
            ret.add(new Point(p.getX(), p.getY() - 1));
        if (p.getY() != cMap[p.getX()].length - 1)
            ret.add(new Point(p.getX(), p.getY() + 1));

        return ret.toArray(new Point[ret.size()]);
    }


    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x : listOfAreas)
            ret.append(x + " ");

        return ret.toString();
    }

}

class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should simply debug your program. Find out what's happening and where it's going wrong. I'd start with some simple prints to see the flow of the program and variable values at different points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `getAdj` code: you are adding points that go down and to the left only when the corresponding coordinate is zero; you should be adding only when it is *not* zero:

```
private Point[] getAdj(Point p, char[][] cMap) {
    List<Point> ret = new ArrayList<Point>();
    if (p.getX() != 0) // <<== Use != instead of ==
        ret.add(new Point(p.getX() - 1, p.getY()));
    if (p.getX() != cMap.length - 1)
        ret.add(new Point(p.getX() + 1, p.getY()));
    if (p.getY() != 0) // <<== Use != instead of ==
        ret.add(new Point(p.getX(), p.getY() - 1));
    if (p.getY() != cMap[p.getX()].length - 1)
        ret.add(new Point(p.getX(), p.getY() + 1));

    return ret.toArray(new Point[ret.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Wow I missed that, buy why didn't it get throw an arrayOutOfBounds exception? once it gets popped in the stack and evaluated in if (cMap[p.getX()][p.getY()] == '0')

Comment: @TristanMilan You're right, it would crash if any of the points on the border are set to `'0'`. However, your map has all `'1'`s on the upper and on the left borders, so the crash never happens.